# mulitiple observers in Ember js

Tags: ember.js

In ember does it make a difference to have mulitiple observers for for one property or to have one observer with all the conditions on the inside?

```
observer_3(
// do stuff here

).observes(var1)

observer_2(
// do stuff here

).observes(var1)

observer_1(
// do stuff here

).observes(var1)
```

**OR**

```
observersvar1(
// do everything here

).observes(var1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having multiple observers for one property **will work without any problems**.

I would go with **multiple observers, when their functionality represent separate concerns**. In contrast i would go with one observer, when you want to have control in which order the logic is excecuted. So **use one observer, when it is part of one concern.**

Answer (score 2):

well, if you have everything in one observer, you have more control over the order in which the code is executed. using multiple observers, on the other hand, makes sense when you're watching a property from different (more or less independent) parts of your application.